# Create automatically a new project or a new unit Delphi on VSCode with Omnipascal

Tags: visual-studio-code, delphi, omnipascal

I've seen that it is possible to load a delphi project into vscode via omnipascal with Loadproject command (http://blog.omnipascal.com/omnipascal-0-13-0-load-project-compile-and-run/)

But I do not find a CreateProject command or CreateUnit to automatically generate these kinds of files.

Is it possible to create a new unit or a new project Delphi  in the same spirit of LoadProject with Omnipascal on VSCode ?

I have found only how to create a new file text but I not found how create a new project (.dpr) or a new unit (.pas) with Omnipascal on VSCode.